# Add a field to the Linux Login

Tags: linux, login, syslog

I want to ask the user the reason for login on Linux Production Servers.

Login prompt will ask as common for user, password and the "Reason for Login" question will be asked afterward and registered in the syslog.

I know it can be done running a script just after login, but how avoid the user to make a crtl-c and by-pass the question?

It is possible to force the answer or logout?

Comment: Alternative: Log when a user does not give a reason, and initiate disciplinary action.  Technology isn't really the medium to solve management problems.

Comment: Or implement a system that requires a log entry be made prior to the login attempt, which temporarily enables login for the account. After a time limit the account can be disabled again or even forced out (@Hyppy is correct that technology isn't a security solution, but if you're going to audit this way there may be easier ways to manage controls and assurances).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to a login script can work when logging in via the BASH shell.

```
trap logout INT
read -p "Answer it or else: " myAnswer
# Log/Handle the answer here.
trap INT
```

It was tested by placing it in a user's .bashrc script, but could be put in a system-wide script.

Comment: you can log something from bash using "logger" command.